# how to make virtual directory in Jboss 4.2.3 with tomcat 5.5?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, server.xml, context.xml

I did that like this in server.xml. It works ok；

```
        <Context path="/webapp/static/images" 
                 docBase="C:/Kurt/jboss/images"
                 reloadable="true">
        </Context>
```

But I DO NOT want to do this in server.xml. Because it needs restart server if any change is made, also sometime it may cause exception. Is there any other way to do that? please advise me and give examples. Thanks.